# Any free SQL/NoSQL databases on trivia/humour/entertainment?

Tags: android, database, xamarin

I'm looking to get into Android development (Xamarin) and to build some simple apps first.

What I have in mind is something trivia-like, with a hosted database (can't find any free & reliable public APIs).

Do you know of any free downloadable databases on the topics of:
- trivia
- humour
- entertainment

http://www.usabledatabases.com/ seemed promising, but it's not free (or I couldn't find any free DBs, as they don't have a price filter).

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you'll find datasets that suit your needs here : https://www.kaggle.com/datasets?sortBy=relevance&group=featured&search=humor

Not related : I consider pretty interesting to stumble across a dataset containing all the transcripts of the presidential debates by typing the keyword "humor" on this website.